# Parsing a SVG - java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

Tags: java, xml, spring, svg

I was trying to parse an SVG file because i want to change some parameter dynamically (trying to set up a live map). I'm working with spring MVC.
It's a simple example because i need to understand how it works.

In my controller I have

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String getHome(ModelMap model) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
        SVGParser parser = new SVGParser(loadSVG());
        model.addAttribute("parser", parser);

        return "home";
    }
```

loadSVG() gives me the xml string of the image (it works if I use it in an `<img>` tag).

```
private String loadSVG() throws IOException{

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("disegno.svg");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        br.close();

        String svgFile = stringBuilder.toString();

        return svgFile;

    }
```

SVGParser.class is

```
public class SVGParser {

    public SVGParser(String uri) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{ //costruttore
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(uri);


        String xpathExpression = "//circle/@id";
        XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression = null;
        NodeList svgPaths = null;
        try {
            expression = xpath.compile(xpathExpression);
            svgPaths = (NodeList)expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        svgPaths.item(0).getNodeValue();

    }


}
```

I just want to see what comes out to understand something, but I got simply:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse-java.io.InputStream-) instead. The method you use expects a string which is in fact a URI to the document.

Also, do not "pre read" the contents, especially since in your case you are doing it wrong (you open a reader without specifying the encoding). Just pass `resource.getInputStream()` to the above method.

And use try-with-resources. Ie, something like this:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

final Document document;

try (
    final InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
) {
    document = builder.parse(in);
}

// work with document
```

Comment: Thanks, exception has gone, now I have an instance of SVGParser, next job is to understand how to get items from it